# jQuery Animate - reverts back to original size

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to resize an image using jquery animate. The animation is working, but when the animation completes, the image reverts back to it's original size. Here's my js & html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id=hBtn]").click(function() {
    $("[id=valueProp]").animate({
      width: '-=350px'
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="valueProp" style="left: 8%; top: 2px; position: absolute; opacity:0.95">
  <img src="slide1.png" width="1152" height="648">
</div>
<button class="btn" id="hBtn">&#8646;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to animate the image, and not the outer div of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to animate the `<img>`, not the container `<div>`... Because once the animation is over, the image simply overflows back to it's defined `width` even if the container is smaller.

And about reverting the animation, use [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) as a flag to know what is the image state and decide.

I also added a delay of 600ms, it is 400ms by default when omited. The other argument is the callback to set the "flag".

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id=hBtn]").click(function() {
    if($("[id=valueProp] img").data("reduced")!=true){
      $("[id=valueProp] img").animate({
        width: '-=350px'
      },600,function(){
        $("[id=valueProp] img").data("reduced",true);
      });
    }else{
      $("[id=valueProp] img").animate({
        width: '+=350px'
      },600,function(){
        $("[id=valueProp] img").data("reduced",false);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="valueProp" style="left: 8%; top: 2px; position: absolute; opacity:0.95">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Liliumbulbiferumflowertop.jpg/220px-Liliumbulbiferumflowertop.jpg" width="1152" height="648">
</div>
<button class="btn" id="hBtn">&#8646;</button>
</div>
```

---

I left your selectors as is... But you can use `#valueProp` instead of `[id=valueProp]`.

Comment: sorry...new to this :)

Answer (score 0):

try to place the **id** into **img** ?

```
<div style="left: 8%; top: 2px; position: absolute; opacity:0.95">
  <img src="slide1.png" id="valueProp" width="1152" height="648">
</div>
<button class="btn" id="hBtn">&#8646;</button>
</div>
```