# Images revert back to normal position

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-animate

OK - I have an issue for which I was able to find a prior thread. Unfortunately, I was not able to find resolution using the solution offered with my own issue.

I am using a single line of code to adjust the height and width of an image.

> $("#myImage").animate({height: "+=15px",width: "+=20px"});

This works exactly as I want it to work from the animation standpoint but as soon as the mouse crosses the boundary of what would be the original dimensions, the image snaps back to that starting size. I have tried some variations of the solution described in the thread below for reference but am coming up short. If I replace the image with just a simple shape it is fine - it seems to only affect images.

[Similar Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162829/jquery-animate-reverts-back-to-original-size)

I am open to some additional suggestions on this one. I must be missing something or not applying it correctly.

---

**Edit -
A little more context...**

I apologize for not offering a bit more context to begin with - I am really a rookie who loves dabbling in this stuff and who loves learning more. I had hoped there was something simple that I might have been overlooking.

The request for more code may be a little tougher than you might expect, but it did force me to write this small action out in a very small file with simple HTML and the JQuery animate line which works perfect and no snapbacks. (my re-write offered below)

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<script>
function grow() {
$("#grass").animate({height: "+=15px",width: "+=20px"});
}
</script>    
<img src="http://www.thirdleveltraining.com/images/grass.jpg" id="grass" width="250" height="250">
</br>
</br>
<button id="myBtn" onclick="grow()">Grow!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

However, the problem is that I am working in the realm of another program (Adobe Captivate) which publishes everything out as HTML5 and JavaScript but everything published out is so crazy dense and cryptic that it is difficult to find exactly what is going on.

When I place an image on the stage and name it 'grass' for example and create a button for the user to click on, I place the line of jQuery highlighted above in an area to execute it when the user clicks the button. The result is that the image expands - which works. In this environment, though - it snaps back.

The image with the name of 'grass' seems to be referenced in the code that Adobe generates in three different places. Two are divs and one is a canvas tag. One div is given an id of 're-grassc', one keeps the original name 'grass' and the canvas tag gets an id of 'grassc'. I have tried animating all these components thinking they maybe had to stay together but that didn't seem to help either. Pic below of the three instances.

[References to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byH8v.png)

I believe my issue has to do with how Adobe is packaging all the stuff up when it converts the project to HTML5 so I am not sure how to otherwise find what you might need. Ugh - sorry. I have combed the page with the console to find some sort of clue as to how I might make this work like my simple file.

Here is a link to a quick published sample of the problem so you can at least see it - if it helps. You'll need to click the ugly play button after it pops up. Just looking for some expert minds to help brainstorm.

[Sample of Problem](http://www.thirdleveltraining.com/captivate/resizeImage/index.html)

I fear this is not adequate but hopefully it is a little something to go on. Let me know if you need a bit more. Thanks to all for any time spent in thought over this. And my apologies if I am barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Can you please post working snippet of your html and js ?

Comment: Thanks for asking, vS12 - I tried to add a little more context to the original post.

Comment: As I currently see it - I need to resize the image itself but am having a hard time actually finding it. It is simply wrapped up in div/canvas tags with a role of img as shown in the pic above. Perhaps I have simply hit a limitation of the software.